# How to convert multipart.File to io.Reader

Tags: go, multipart

Maybe I'm just not understanding how to use the `Read` method for the `File` object, but I see in docs that `io.Reader` is within the `multipart.File` interface, but I don't understand how to access it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types *An interface T may use a (possibly qualified) interface type name E in place of a method specification. This is called embedding interface E in T; it adds all (exported and non-exported) methods of E to the interface T.* That is, you do not access the reader because there is no io.Reader in multipart.File, instead [`multipart.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File) has all of the methods that the 4 embedded interfaces have and you can access those methods directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that the `multipart.File` interface includes the `io.Reader` interface, so any object that is a valid `multipart.File` is also a valid `io.Reader`. Therefore, you can call the `Read` method (as defined by `io.Reader`) on an object of type `multipart.File`.